# Should this static cast from int to double be avoided?

Tags: c++, casting

Consider:

```
int total = 14; // something for which double does not make sense
int nPeople = 5;
double perCapita = static_cast<double>(total) / nPeople; // should this cast be avoided?
```

Should one avoid casting in this case? Is it better to write `1.0 * total / nPeople` or something else?

Comment: That's okay I think. It shows intent which is important. On the other hand, perhaps you start out with the wrong types for `total` or `nPeople` instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Are you saying that multiplying by 1.0 is worse because it is less explicit?

Comment: Yes. Without a comment about why you do the multiplication it's not really clear why you do it. And depending on the compiler, it might also incur run-time overhead if it's not able to deduce that the meaning of the multiplication is a type conversion. If you want to do a type conversion, use the type conversion "functions" instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Your suggestion to start with wrong types surprises me. Isn't specifying a wrong type misleading?

Comment: No I mean perhaps the variables should be of type `double` instead of `int`? Without more context (and requirements/assignment) it's hard for us to say.

Comment: Specifically the `total` variable. Whose sum does it represent?

Comment: @CinCout See the comment in the code: `total` represents something for which `double` does not make sense.

Comment: In that case, an explicit cast makes the intent clear. Multiplying with `1.0` doesn't.

Comment: I agree, doing the cast is the better option, and if you want to be extra clear for anybody skimming your code (and who may have forgotten the variable types), then just add a small comment: `static_cast<double>(total) / nPeople; // cast to avoid integer division`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should one avoid casting in this case? Is it better to write 1.0 *
>   total / nPeople or something else?

Multiplying with 1.0 does not make the intent clear. An explicit cast here is much clearer and is the de-facto accepted way of doing this operation. It would have been neat if we had some kind of template function that could be explicitly called (one not called `std::div` - since that is a different kind of division) - but alas we do not, and until that point - just `static_cast<double>` away !